# What review audit is this?

Tags: bug, review-audit

[image]

[The review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1370162)

This is a review audit. But the system shouldn't trick me to say this is a possible spam. I almost fell for it. Luckily, I pressed the vote count and found that this is an audit. Is this a bug or just some kind of audit trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of an audit is to make you stop and think. Or to document that you're not doing that.

It made you stop and think. So it did its job just fine.

(I should note that failing an audit on occasion is not a big deal, the issue is when you fail *a lot* of them.)

Answer (score 0):

The OP and I have about he same reputation, so I'll guess that they are starting to do more review queue work, like I am. And for me the whole thing with review audits (that they exist, what their goal is, how they work) came almost completely out of left field (i.e. as an unpleasant surprise). It went from "Cool, they are trusting me more" to "Oh, they don't trust me."

I now see why review audits exist and agree they are a good idea, but think it would be good if they didn't come as such a surprise. Sadly I don't have any good suggestions, but I am posting this answer 1) so that OP realizes they aren't alone in this, and 2) letting mods know that this is an issue, albeit a minor one.

Comment: If you are attacking the review queues *honestly* and in good faith, you have nothing to fear from audits.  You will occasionally get the "wrong" answer (along with the condescending message that comes with a wrong answer), but mostly the audits will just pass you by.  Don't stress it. ;)